# Checking Spring Boot (Webflux) filter performance

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm currently working on performance audit of a mega-monolith Spring Boot application. They'd like to eventually split it out into nice clean microservices, but they need it to keep running in the meantime.

We've noticed a huge (around 2-5 seconds) delay in web requests, and we suspect that there's something gumming up the works in the filter chain (which is massive). However, I'm not sure how to introspect the filters and their timing, and Google is being especially unhelpful on this one.

Comment: have you tried adding code to time each of the web filters? This should help identify the problematic filter and narrow down the code.

Comment: @Michael McFadyen I don't control all of the filters, which is what makes it difficult. I tried adding some timing filters before each of the existing ones,  but WebFilterChain's list is immutable so I can't add them directly.

Comment: I may try just hacking in a changed list with reflection. If I can do that then I can install timing filters before everything.